# How can i handle invalid input to cin(cpp)

Tags: c++, stream, char, cin, fflush

when i use the code below,

```
char command;
cin >> command;
```

i want to get only ('a','c','d') as inputs.
In other alphabet(int) cases, i can solve the problem using 'switch statement'

But when someone types multiple characters, my program doesn't know what is the problem.
Just, take one charcter of multiple characters.

In conclusion, I want to detect the multiple character input case.
And this happens, i want to print error, then program to keep running.

Comment: You could use `std::getline` instead and process the logic depending on the string size

Comment: read a string then parse the individual characters. Reading a string rarely fails

Comment: there are loads of questions and answers on how to validate user input. Did you try any?

Comment: Learning to program is also learning how to find information and teach yourself. For example: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/stdcin-and-handling-invalid-input/